# A getter in a non-virtual interface with a chained method

Tags: c++, class, methods, getter-setter

I have the following interface that can return a map with a pair of int and string for key and string as a value.

```
class Foo {
    public:
        virtual ~Foo() = default;
        Foo& operator=( const Foo& ) = delete; 
        std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>, std::string> save_to_map(const std::string filename) {return getRecord(filename);}

    private:
        virtual std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>, std::string> getRecord(const std::string filename) = 0;
};

class Bar final : public Foo {
    public:
        Bar() = default;

    private:    
        std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>, std::string> getRecord(const std::string filename) override {
            std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>, std::string> fullRecord; 
            fullRecord[std::make_pair(0, "A")] = "text";
            fullRecord[std::make_pair(0, "B")] = "2";
            fullRecord[std::make_pair(0, "C")] = "3.41";
            
            return fullRecord;
        }
};
```

I am initializing the object with a factory function and I can access the values of the map the usual way.

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo > fac_func(){
    auto dbi = std::make_unique<Bar>();
    
    return dbi;
} 

int main(){
    auto p = fac_func();
    auto m = p ->save_to_map("path\to\file");
    
    std::cout<<m[std::make_pair(0, "A")]<<'\n';
    std::cout<<m.at(std::make_pair(0, "B"))<<'\n';
}
```

Now I want to have an access to the values by the two values of the key with an addition of a chained methods which convert the values to the standard types of int, double or string if possible. But in my head I have no grasp of the best practice to achieve this. Like do I need to have a map extra as a private member or do I need a special kind of a factory function? In the end it should be something like this:

```
std::string s = p -> Get(0, "A").AsString();
int i = p -> Get(0, "B").AsInt();
```

EDIT: As requested I am adding the additional code that I removed for the sake of having a minimal example. So getRecord looks like that:

```
        std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>, std::string> getRecord(const std::string tableName) override {
            std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>, std::string> fullRecord;
            column_names = get_column_names(tableName);
            std::string sqlExpr = "Select * from " + tableName;
            tableSelect(fullRecord, sqlExpr, column_names);

            return fullRecord;
        }
```

And this is tableSelect

```
void SqliteDB :: tableSelect(std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>, std::string>  &record_map, const std::string sqlExpr, const std::vector<std::string> &params){

    unsigned int columnCount;
    const unsigned char *columnText;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlDb, sqlExpr.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL);

    if(!params.empty()){
        for(size_t i = 0; i<params.size(); ++i){
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, i+1, params[i].c_str(), params[i].length(), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
    }

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout<<"error: "<<sqlite3_errmsg(sqlDb)<<'\n';
     return;
    }

    for(size_t j = 0; sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW; ++j) {

        columnCount = sqlite3_data_count(stmt);
        for(size_t i = 0; i<columnCount; ++i){
            columnText = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, i);
            if(columnText != NULL){
                record_map[std::make_pair(j, params[i])] = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(columnText);
            }
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```

Comment: This looks terribly inefficient. Why are you passing around full `map`s by value? After you've gotten a map from `fac_func` then `p->Get`  will know nothing about that map. Keep the map internal to `Foo` or `Bar` and add querying member functions instead. Also, what is `tableName`? It's not used

Comment: If you explain a bit more about details what this is supposed to be used for and where `filename´ comes into play, it'll be easier to provide an answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo filename is just the path to a sqlite file with a DB from which I am reading the tables, I am reading records and storing them by row index and column name into the map. The tables are tiny so it does not matter that I am using a map, I think.

Comment: Ok, but can you show how you use it in your code? Right now there's a disconnect since `getRecord` doesn't use it at all. Also, if you read the db, don't you get the correct types in the tables?

Comment: @TedLyngmo SQLite has a feature that it does not give a damn about the declared column types. There is nothing stopping you adding text into the integer columns for example. So that is why I decided to read everything as string and convert it with chained methods if it is possible. The method how I feel the map is probably not essential here, but I added it, as you requested.

Comment: I see, but it _has_ declared column types so you could populate proper data types directly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15848742/7582247) seems to be one example.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a class which has the methods `AsString`, `AsInt`, etc.

```cpp
class StrUtil
{
private:
    const std::string &m_rStr;
public:
    StrUtil( const std::string &Str ) : m_rStr{Str} {}
    const std::string &AsString() const {   return m_rStr;  }
    int AsInt() const { return std::stoi( m_rStr ); }
};
```

Next, create map-like class that provides method returns `StrUtil` instead of raw `std::string`.

```cpp
class MapLike
{
public:
    MapLike()
    {//This is test code
        m_Map[ std::make_pair( 0, "A") ] = "text";
        m_Map[ std::make_pair( 0, "B") ] = "2";
        m_Map[ std::make_pair( 0, "C") ] = "3.14";
    }
public:
    StrUtil operator()( unsigned int Key1, const std::string &Key2 ) const
    {
        auto iElem = m_Map.find( std::make_pair(Key1,Key2) );
        return StrUtil( iElem!=m_Map.end()  ?  iElem->second  :  "" );
    }
private:
    std::map< std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>, std::string > m_Map;
};

//test
int main()
{
    MapLike M;
    std::cout << M( 0, "A" ).AsString() << '\n';
    std::cout << M( 0, "B" ).AsInt() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for AsInt as it crashes.

Comment: Yes, in the first place, "Parse as integer" like process can not work for all arbitrary strings.
This example code does not treat such point, because I think such point is not the focus of this question